# Attempting to grep positional parameters

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting, grep

```
#! /bin/bash
sum=0
for number in $@
do
    sum=$(( sum + number ))


done
grep [!0-9+-] "$@" | echo $sum
```

The script is intended to take the positional parameters and add them together, however I also need the script to do two more operations.

1. If a positional parameter is a word then print the word on the STDOUT
2. If there is a positional parameter that isn't a number then print error message.

When I run this script, grep searches my current directory for any other dir or files for the expressions I input. I need grep to search the positional paramters for words and then produce them to the stdout. Currently the output is only the sum of the arguments and it does not recognize or produce any messages when letters are used.

Comment: What is the end-goal here?

Comment: It's just to add numbers together, and present an error message if a word or letter appears. I removed the echo $sum for now.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modified. A few examples would go a long way to helping you.

Comment: No problem FankerZ, I thought my post was clear but I clarified it a little further. Essentially everytime I attempt to use grep within the script, it starts searching for files and directories when I want it to search within the positional paramters.

Comment: `If a positional parameter is a word` is the same as `If there is a positional parameter that isn't a number`

Comment: `for number in "$@"; do if [[ $number =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then echo "$number is not a number"; else sum=((sum+number)); fi; done`

Answer (score 0):

This is where I was going to suggest your adjustment. I assume you're using arguments on your file since you're using $@... You'll also need to use -E for regular expression searches.

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
homeworkassignment=1
wordfound=false
for number in $@
do
    evaluate=$(echo "$number" | grep [!0-9+-])
    #check for numbers in $@
    if [ $? = '0' ]; then
    numericvalue=$(echo $number | grep [!0-9+-])
        sum=$(( $sum + $numericvalue ))
    else
        if [ $homeworkassignment=1 ]; then echo "NO NUMBER"; fi
        if [ $homeworkassignment=2 ]; then wordfound=true; fi
    fi
done
echo "The Total Sum is "$sum
if ([ $homeworkcode -eq 2] && [ $wordfound -eq "true" ] ); then echo "A Word was Found"'!';fi
```

Output:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ./so_38517168.sh 2 1 2 3 4 NO NUMBERS 1 NO NUMBERS 2 NO NUMBERS 3 NO NUMBERS 4
NO NUMBERS
NO NUMBERS
NO NUMBERS
NO NUMBERS
NO NUMBERS
NO NUMBERS
NO NUMBERS
NO NUMBERS
2 1 2 3 4 NO NUMBERS 1 NO NUMBERS 2 NO NUMBERS 3 NO NUMBERS 4

The Total Sum is 22
```

Noting that the line that extracted 2 1 2 3 4 NO NUMBERS 1 NO NUMBERS 2 NO NUMBERS 3 NO NUMBERS 4 is because the entire line matched a number. You would need to use probably sed to accomplish showing only the numbers from this output.

Comment: I updated my question. Putting echo $sum before the grep resulted in no output at all. However, my problem isn't solved as it only outputs the sum of the arguments, any letters are ignored.

Comment: I simply get a sum of the arguments. For example if I put 1 2 3 4 as arguments, the output is 10. Now what I want it to do is, if I put one two 3 4 as arguments I want the output to say 7 one two Only numbers are valid.

Comment: add2 1 2 3 4
NO NUMBERS 1
NO NUMBERS 2
NO NUMBERS 3
NO NUMBERS 4

Should be noted that I used NO NUMBERS instead of No numbers in value

Comment: It's just a homework assignment so there is no real end-game here. Just a simple script to get used to using grep in scripts. I guess the script will simply add numerical arguments and ultimately discard letters, and present an error message after the sum of the numerical arguments.

Comment: Well if you want only a single error, just use a Boolean switch.

Comment: Well first the assignment wants me to print the word in the output, then it wants me to create a single error message (which i have done in previous assignments)      Thanks for the help, it has expanded my mind and given me a few options to search through so I no longer feel stuck. Good night.

Comment: So... popped an update right - so this code shows for both homework assignments based on whether or not the value is set to 1 or 2.